# jsx problem displaying a phone number in one line

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a simple problem, but I could not figure out the solution for it.
I have this element

```
<tr className="list-group-item list-item row">
    <td className="col">Phone number :</td>
    <td className="col">{this.state.phone_number}{""}</td>
</tr>
```

I expect it to display one line row like this

```
Phone number :        +1 773-381-0000
```

however it displays this

```
                      +1 
Phone number :        773-
                      381-
                      0000
```

Comment: You had better to add all the jsx code, and the referenced css files to the question.

Comment: just give the fixed width(till full number can be seen) to phone number td

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `nowrap` attribute to display properly.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_nowrap

```
<tr className="list-group-item list-item row">
       <td className="col">Phone number :</td>
       <td  style="white-space: nowrap;" className="col">{this.state.phone_number}{""}</td>
</tr>
```

Your problem is that there is not enough space in the table and the text wraps.

The `row` and `col` bootstrap classes don't work well with tables. Check responsive table here https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/tables/responsive/

Comment: I didn't have success. but when I do ```<td >Phone number :</td>
       <td >{this.state.phone_number}{""}</td>``` I get something like ```Phone number :+1 773-381-0000            ```  but I want some space in between the two

Comment: Try to force some width to the second td. Either percentage or even better some fixed value that will accommodate all values.

Comment: I did ```                    <td width="75%">Phone number :</td>
                    <td width="33%">+1 504-254-0000{""}</td>``` but it does not display well unless I use ```className="col"``` the problem is that if I replace "-" by "." it display normal